# JQuery TableSorter Plugin: Dynamically enable and disable header sorting

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have a table that utilizes the TableSorter plugin for JQuery - side not the table is generated server side via PHP. Initially the table is correctly setup and the sorting and pagination works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#news").tablesorter({sortList:[[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]], widgets: ['zebra']})
                .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pagination")});
    });
```

There are instances on the page where I want to disable the sorting and then re-enable it via user interaction.

Is there a way to fire off a JavaScript call within the php page to toggle specific headers to be sortable or not.  Basically just dynamically turn on and off the header sorting functionality of the particular table.

Any input is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try my fork of [tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) I have on github. I added the option to change the sorter using class names. Here is [a demo](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html), they should work dynamically.

```
<table class="tablesorter"> 
  <thead> 
    <tr> 
      <th class="sorter-false">Index</th> 
      <th>Name</th> 
      <th>Address</th> 
    </tr> 
  </thead> 
  <tbody>
  ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you experimented with setting the "headers" object as demonstrated in this example?
http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html

Comment: I have - maybe my JavaScript is lacking here.  Using the thought of putting in a JS function that can be triggered by the user I created a disableTableSorter and enableTablesorter.  However initial load of the page the news table is disabled from the start with the following JS.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'> 
     $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#news").tablesorter({sortList:[[1,1],[2,1],[3,1]], widgets: ['zebra']})
                 .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pagination")});
     });
     function disableTableSorter(){
   $("#news").tablesorter({headers: {1: {sorter: false},2: {sorter: false},3: {sorter: false}}});   
  });
  
  function enableTableSorter(){
   $("#news").tablesorter({headers: {1: {sorter: true},2: {sorter: true},3: {sorter: true}}});   
  }); 
       
    </script>

Comment: If you published your code in an example using JSBin or JSFiddle, you'd have better luck getting help in your troubleshooting efforts.

Comment: Marc - I greatly appreciate your input and recommendation on the JSBin. I checked that out and found my issue immediately. Ultimately this is the classic example of me not checking things thoroughly enough before posting and asking for input - may bad.  Thanks